# How to import a Python file with a variable name?

Tags: python

I need to import a python file lets name it 123xzy.py
My problem is that this file name starts with numbers, and changes with every use.

I tried to use the following approach:

```
vt=str(sys.argv[2])
import vt
```

but its not working. If you know a way to import a python file with a variable name please let me know.

Thank you :)

Comment: Could also do `module_123 = __import__("123")`

Comment: "its not working" is not very descriptive. Please provide a [mcve] and give the full traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the standard library package [importlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html):

```
import importlib
import sys
vt = importlib.import_module(sys.argv[2])
```

Comment: If you are still having trouble check out the dupe, it has a lot of answers with more detailed explanantions

Comment: Also your module name should not end with .py

Comment: ok the problem is solved, thank you
I only had to remove the .py part from argv[2] befor the import line
vt=re.sub('.py$','',vt)